# renderDT shows only headers and none of the rows

Tags: r, shiny, dt

This is a very strange problem and I have been breaking my head for last few hours. Have got a replicable example below. It appears to be a bug in shiny R DT package.

So let's see what's happening.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

df1 <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    DTOutput("list1")
    #DTOutput("list2")
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$list1 <- renderDT(df1)
  output$list2 <- renderDT(mtcars)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The above code does not display the simple data.frame of 10 rows. Instead just shows an empty table. Screenshot attached.

[image: Rstudio viewer screenshot with blank output]

But very surprisingly if I just replace the data.frame by `mtcars` it is correctly displayed. You just need to uncomment the next `DTOutput` line. And comment the first `DTOutput` before running the shinyapp.

```
 #DTOutput("list1")
 DTOutput("list2")
```

Screenshot after we comment out the previous `DTOutput` and uncomment the next one [image: mtcars].

**UPDATE**

Narrowing down the problem further I observe the same symptoms while outputting a datatable using the `DT` R package without using `shiny`.

Trying

```
DT::datatable(data = data.frame(name=letters,age=1:13))
```

I just see `name`,`age` in the Rstudio Viewer as well as chrome browser and no contents of the table.

[image]

Comment: The example you posted works perfectly fine when i tested it.

Comment: Ah! But to eliminate the Rstudio and R environments I tried on another machine (iMAC), with the same problem.

Comment: Tried again. But no success. Which browser did you use @Sada93? Could you please try on Chrome as well? Thanks

Comment: Tried Chrome Browser

Comment: Very strange, as I also use chrome

Comment: The example you posted works for me as well. What version of DT are you using? You can check it with 'sessionInfo()'

Comment: Here's the version details of DT  `DT            0.5.1    2018-11-16 [1] Github (rstudio/DT@1b09c29)`

Comment: Here are the full sessionInfo output.`> sessionInfo("DT")
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
character(0)

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.5.1`

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but I also had a (different) problem with that version. I reinstalled version 0.4 using devtools::install_version("DT", "0.4"), you could try that as well. Is there any error in the web console of chrome?

Comment: So should I revert to 0.4 and test out? Right now did you test with DT_0.4 or DT_0.5?

Comment: Is there any solution now? I have the same exact problem using DT_0.9. For me even the mtcars example does not work with the above code.